# Why i dont get the channel blue, green or red with this short code in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

```
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(rgb(:,:,1));
```

When i put this the image is grey, not green or blue or red. Why is that?
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image is grey because you are looking at values for only one color, MATLAB sees values for a color, but there is no way for it to know *what* color it is, which is why it displays grey.

As an example, what color is the value 154? When you pass just a matrix of values into `imshow` it will show it in grey scale.

`imshow(rgb(:,:,1)); %Shows the values of the red component of the image in grey`

```
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
r = rgb;
r(:,:,2:3) = 0; % The red component without the other components
g = rgb;
g(:,:,1:2:3) = 0; % The green component without the other components
b = rgb;
b(:,:,1:2) = 0; % The blue component without the other components
figure();
imshow(r);
figure();
imshow(g);
figure();
imshow(b);
```

Doing the above will allow you to see the representation of the magnitudes of the colors in their own color value.

Comment: So, i supose that i need to specified map of colors. I need to say to him that 0 is blue and 255 is white. Thanks, i supose that i need to post other question how to do that. O.o Thankyou

Comment: @user1792426 No that's incorrect...wait 1 minute and I'll post a note on the answer.

Comment: I thought this because if a made im(:,:,2:3) = 0; imshow(im); this is show properly. The only diference is the map of colors. I supose...

Comment: @user1792426 You're correct, I must not have understood your first comment. I updated the answer to reflect how to get the r, g, and b images (in their respective colors).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to only display one color channel, set the other color channels to zero:

```
peppers = imread('peppers.png');
onlyred_peppers = peppers;
onlyred_peppers(:,:,2:3)=0;
imshow(onlyred_peppers);
```

[image]

If you feed `imshow` only `peppers(:,:,1)`, you're giving it just a `NxMx1` matrix, which is interpreted by imshow as grayscale, see [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/imshow.html).

If you really want, you can change the colormap to change the grayscale image to redscale:

```
imshow(peppers(:,:,1));
cm_red = [linspace(0,1,256)' zeros(256,2)];
colormap(cm_red);
```

which will give you the same image as above.

If you also want to scale the color span in the image you load to use the full available span (0-1 / 0-255), you can do that with:

```
red_scaled_peppers = peppers(:,:,1);
red_scaled_peppers = double(red_scaled_peppers)/double(max(red_scaled_peppers(:)));
imshow(red_scaled_peppers);
colormap([linspace(0,1,256)' zeros(256,2)]);
```

which makes no difference, because in this case, red channel color span is already maxed out.

Comment: thank you, but i know that. I just dont know if because the map of colors or not.@NominSim says that the difference is not that i supose Im just waiting for his note. Thank you

Comment: look at my last remark, I'll also add something about changing the colormap

Comment: yes i figureout this solution too. But the problem of use colormap is that you can jump color for example i do this:
colormap([[0:1/255:1]', zeros(256,1), zeros(256,1)])
So my step of color is 1/255 but may be the real image for blue or green or red has color with a diference less than 1/255.

Comment: that depends on the image you load, type `double` will assume channel intensity between 0 and 1, type `uint` is 0 to 255. For this reason alone just working on the original image is best. I think you also mean that you want to scale the total color span to use the total available scale, ie if the image contains color values 0-200, scale it so it displays as 0-255, see edit for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) color model represents color by "mixing" the red, green and blue colors in some proportion. All you need to know is a color is represented by 3 numbers.

Therefore, your `rgb` image is represented by 3 matrices where `rgb(:,:,1)` represents the red layer. Now, if you looked at `rgb(:,:,1)` you'd see a bunch of numbers (probably between 0 - 255 or 0 - 1).

So element `rgb(i,j,1)` represents the red component at pixel `(i,j)`. Therefore, displaying the matrix `rgb(:,:,1)` merely displays a matrix with a bunch of values which is displayed as grayscale (where 0 = black and 255 = white).